# Can I create a gmatch pattern that returns a variadic number of values?

Tags: lua, lpeg

I need to iterate over some pairs of strings in a program that I am writing. Instead of putting the string pairs in a big table-of-tables, I am putting them all in a single string, because I think the end result is easier to read:

```
function two_column_data(data)
  return data:gmatch('%s*([^%s]+)%s+([^%s]+)%s*\n')
end

for a, b in two_column_data [[
  Hello  world
  Olá    hugomg
]] do
  print( a .. ", " .. b .. "!")
end
```

The output is what you would expect:

```
Hello, world!
Olá, hugomg!
```

However, as the name indicates, the `two_column_data` function only works if there are two exactly columns of data. How can I make it so it works on any number of columns?

```
for x in any_column_data [[
  qwe
  asd
]] do
  print(x)
end

for x,y,z in any_column_data [[
  qwe rty uio
  asd dfg hjk
]] do
  print(x,y,z)
end
```

I'm OK with using lpeg for this task if its necessary.

Comment: `function k_column_data(k, data)
  return data:gmatch(('%s*(%S+)'):rep(k))
end`

Comment: @Egor I think the point is he don't know what 'k' will be

Comment: OP, I think this should work: first capture each whole line, and then capture each word, put the words in a table, and unpack them on return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an lpeg re version

```lua
function re_column_data(subj)
    local t, i = re.compile([[
          record <- {| ({| [ %t]* field ([ %t]+ field)* |} (%nl / !.))* |}
          field <- escaped / nonescaped
          nonescaped <- { [^ %t"%nl]+ }
          escaped <- '"' {~ ([^"] / '""' -> '"')* ~} '"']], { t = '\t' }):match(subj)
    return function()
        local ret 
        i, ret = next(t, i)
        if i then
            return unpack(ret)
        end
    end
end
```

It basicly is a redo of the CSV sample and supports quoted fields for some nice use-cases: values with spaces, empty values (""), multi-line values, etc.

```
for a, b, c in re_column_data([[
    Hello  world "test
test"
    Olá    "hug omg"
""]].."\tempty a") do
    print( a .. ", " .. b .. "! " .. (c or ''))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function any_column_data(data)
  local f = data:gmatch'%S[^\r\n]+'
  return
    function()
      local line = f()
      if line then
        local row, ctr = line:gsub('%s*(%S+)','%1 ')
        return row:match(('(.-) '):rep(ctr))
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: This returns a final nil, nil pair for OP input

Comment: @wqw - It seems to [work](https://eval.in/493736) as required.  Please post a code with wrong behavior.

Comment: My bad. I had some extra spaces on last line ot test input.

Comment: @wqw - Like in [this](https://eval.in/493746) code?  Yes, it may be a problem after formatting the code.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
local function any_column_data( str )
    local pos = 0
    return function()
        local _, to, line = str:find("([^\n]+)\n", pos)
        if line then
            pos = to
            local words = {}
            line:gsub("[^%s]+", function( word )
                table.insert(words, word)
            end)
            return table.unpack(words)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Grumbling? Don't you want this person to understand what's in his code?

Comment: @warspyking, I don't care about him, just wanted to try to write the algo ) Seems like Egor Skriptunoff made it shorter and clearer.

Comment: Looks like Louis feels the same way. There's no point in giving someone code unless they understand why it works, you'll just get more questions with same problem due to lack if sufficient information in his previous questions.

Answer (score 1):

Outer loop returns lines, and inner loop returns words in line.

```
s = [[
  qwe rty uio
  asd dfg hjk
]]

for s in s:gmatch('(.-)\n') do
  for s in s:gmatch('%w+') do
    io.write(s,' ')
  end
  io.write('\n')
end
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations.

Comment: Unless the code (as in this case) is self evident to even a beginner programmer.  Otherwise, I would have to teach Computer Science with each answer I give. :)

Comment: maybe to you and the asker. But keep in mind, that you are not alone. Just explain why your answer solve the issue, where was the mistake, what do you use to solve the issue, etc... I recommend you to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer carefully.